# Redirect https://www.mydomain.com to https://mydomain.com in Play framework

Tags: playframework

We're using Play 1.2.4 for a project. For our users who browse to "https://www.mydomain.com", we want to redirect them to "https://mydomain.com".

Once our webapp is deployed, there will be no front-end web server like Apache. It will all be run on Play. (We already have the HTTPS stuff working. That was easy in Play.)

When testing in development, we can add foo.localdomain and bar.localdomain to our /etc/hosts files to simulate this and then do it for real in production.

Any idea on how to redirect www.mydomain.com to simply mydomain.com in a pure Play environment?

Answer (score 1):

We sorted it out. The solution works in dev, and we expect it to work fine in prod.

We added a @Before method to our Controller class that works like this:

```
@Before
public static void redirectIfNeeded() {
  String baseUrl = play.Play.configuration.getProperty("application.baseUrl");
  if (baseUrl.indexOf(request.domain) == -1) {
      redirect(baseUrl);
  }
}
```

In short, every time a controller method is called, we make sure the calling domain is mydomain.com (as specified in application.conf in the application.baseUrl property) and not www.mydomain.com. If it isn't mydomain.com, redirect to mydomain.com.

Comment: What if request contains parameters ? You will be always redirected to root instead